# Google maps places Api Not working for Android App

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

my api key  is working correctly i am using google places api but when I use it in my andoprid app it gives

```
I/flutter (14432): {error_message: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, predictions: [], status: REQUEST_DENIED}
I/flutter (14432): ====> API Call: /api/v1/config/place-api-autocomplete?search_text=Nagpur
I/flutter (14432): Header: {Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, zoneId: [1], X-localization: en, latitude: "21.1326133", longitude: "79.0988967", Authorization: Bearer null}
D/EGL_emulation(14432): app_time_stats: avg=333.35ms min=133.37ms max=499.84ms count=3
I/flutter (14432): ====> API Response: [200] /api/v1/config/place-api-autocomplete?search_text=Nagpur
I/flutter (14432): {error_message: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, predictions: [], status: REQUEST_DENIED}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example]() that demonstrates the issue. What we only know is that you might not be using an API key in your App, or you have put an invalid one. But we have no way of knowing since you did not provide code for us to debug. Are you by any means using the same API key for both your Places API and Android?